# How to clear indicators in the Bootstrap carousel?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How to clear indicators in the Bootstrap carousel? Now I have text + indicators at the bottom. But I want to save just Text, without indicators

I have to have just Text, so when I will click on them, images will change.

P.S I want to show screen, but I do not have enough reputation here

http://gyazo.com/ff38809ed5b4356a69e2ab4b0b17adc1

Comment: Hey! Is anybody here?

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped if you posted your code , because we would directly tell you what to remove. find the code that resembles this the most:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
```

and delete it !